# Send fax programmatically using fax modem

Tags: c#, fax

We need to be able to send faxes from windows service (C#) over connected fax modem. We have tried to use build-in FAXCOMEXLib library but had so many issues with it (producing a lot of errors) plus it's not very configurable (not even able to select fax quality).

Can someone suggest alternative library that is actively supported? It doesn't have to be free. Please do not suggest online fax services as all of them are charging per page and with required volume of faxes they become unacceptably expensive.

Comment: Do you still have a real analogue telephone line? Fax only works good with a real analogue line, those new digital lines plus analogue converter cause a lot of problems.

Comment: Yes, we use regular landline telephone lines for faxes.